# Change from wamp to xamp

Tags: xampp, wamp

I wrote a php script and ran it on xampp server first , later I downloaded wamp and executed the same script . I found xampp server to be more friendly to me and uninstalled wamp but when i try to start my xampp server and run my php script again, It uses the wamp server , though i uninstalled it . I was unable to find solutions online and one solution of using appcmd didnot work . Can anyone else suggest me other options ?

Comment: I'm not clear how it could be using wamp if uninstalled ... how can you tell?

Comment: when you start apache server and run the html file , it shows wamp symbol on the title and states the access is denied

Comment: Thanks , I have found the solution to the problem . I changed the hdconf contents from "request all denied" to "allow from all" and it worked . This maybe because wamp server could have modified the contents of xampp .

Comment: Good. Thanks for posting what you've found, as it may help others.